# ¿Cómo proteger un setter de una de una entidad de estado en mi capa de dominio, para que solo sea asignable mediante un método en mi capa de servicio?

Tags: c#

Tengo dividido mi proyecto en varias capas (`Class library`). Las importantes en este caso son la de servicio (mi lógica de negocio) y la de dominio (mi definición de las entidades). Una relación de ejemplo (de las tantas que tienen asociadas una entidad estado) seria una de tipo `Delivery` (simplificada):

```
public class Delivery
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string DestinyDirection { get; set; }

    public int OrderID { get; set; }

    public int DeliveryStateID { get; set; } // Propiedad que solo quiero que sea seteable mediante 
                                             // un método que valide lógica de negocio
}
```

Y una del tipo `DeliveryState`:

```
public class DeliveryState
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string StateName{ get; set; }
}
```

Como se ve, la relación entre la entidad `Delivery` y la entidad `DeliveryState` se da mediante la propiedad `DeliveryStateID`. Lo que yo quiero, es poder **delegar** la asignación de los diferentes estados que puede tomar, mediante métodos en mi capa de servicio (que es donde tiene que ir lo relacionado a mi lógica de negocio) para, en resumen, poder cambiar de estados solo mediante estos métodos, que validarán que se cumplan mis reglas de negocio para poder cambiar de un estado **A** a un **B**, y en caso de no cumplirse, lanzar una excepción, y que estos, **SOLO** sean asignables usando estos métodos en dicha capa, y no directamente con un `setter` en la capa de dominio.

Lo que probé también, es marcar como `protected` el `setter`, e intentar mediante herencia que una clase obtenga acceso a esos métodos, pero no me funciono del todo bien.

Comment: Prueba con `private set;`

Comment: Claro, eso seria una parte de la solución, pero mi problema, es como delegar esos métodos a mi capa de servicio donde tengo toda mi lógica de negocio, y no colocarla en mi clase donde tengo mi definición de la entidad (en mi capa de dominio). Sino estaría mezclando la responsabilidad de las capas (por lo menos en mi punto de vista según la teoría de la función de cada capa). (hice un edit en la pregunta).